# Question about notation for rewriting integral of Laplace Beltrami operator

Tags: operator-theory, laplacian, self-adjoint-operators

I was just reading about the [Laplace Beltrami operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator), which is a linear, second order, self-adjoint operator on a general Riemannian metric $g_\mu\nu$ space.

$$\Delta A_{\mu}=\nabla^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}A_{\mu}$$

Where $A_\alpha$ is some arbitrary vector field component on M that the operator is acting on. Suppose We're looking at some integral over the manifold $M$ such as:

$$\intop_{M}B^{\alpha}\Delta A_{\alpha}dvol_{M}$$

Where $B^\alpha$ is another vector field component. Invoking the self-adjointness of $\Delta$ One may write this as:

$$\intop_{M}B^{\alpha}\Delta A_{\alpha}dvol_{M}=\intop_{M}<dB^{\alpha},dA_{\alpha}>dvol_{M}=\intop_{M}A^{\alpha}\Delta B_{\alpha}dvol_{M}$$

This might be a dumb question, but is the $d$ in the middle equation the exterior derivative of $A,B$ (respectively)? The paper I was reading skipped the derivation, and didn't explain the notation (same with the wiki page).

Answer (score 1):

If the connection is the Levi-Civita of the metric then the exterior derivative is obtained antisymmetrizing the covariant derivative of the form.
If your manifold is orientable and closed then you have in general that
$\int_M \langle B,  \nabla^* \nabla A\rangle = \int_M \langle \nabla B, \nabla A \rangle$. Then alternating and using the inner product on forms (at this point using the metric we regard $B$ and $A$ as forms) you should get that $\int_M \langle \nabla B, \nabla A \rangle = \int_M \langle d B^\sharp, d A^\sharp \rangle$.

Comment: +1  I'm rather new to musical (sharp here) isomorphisms between the tangent and cotangent bundle, is there a reasonable way to write this in component notation? So not the exterior derivative, but rather just the inner product of forms (1-forms in this case)?

Comment: Let me put this into context: If we suppose the Manifold is a Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $g$ and the forms $A,B\epsilon g$. Would it be correct to say that, for the Levi-Cevita connecton (denoted $\nabla$):

$$\intop_{M}B\nabla^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}Advol_{M}=\intop_{M}<DB,DA>dvol_{M}=\intop_{M}<\Omega,\Omega>dvol_{M} $$

Where $D$ denotes the exterior covariant derivative (using the Levi-Cevita connection) and thus $\Omega$ is Cartan's curvature two-form (which is also $g$ valued?)

Comment: Why $DB=DA$? and also I am confused by your notation. Usually the Curvature form arises in the following situation: given a principal $G$ bundle $P\to M$ and a connection form $\omega$, then we can compute the covariant derivative $D\omega = \Omega$ which is the curvature, notice that the operator $D$ depends on the choosen connection $\omega$ and changing connection form we get different curvature forms.

Comment: Apologies I meant to index the Cartan two forms $\Omega_A ,\Omega_B $ respectively.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this but would that be the same as writing the laplacian as: $(d+\delta)^2$ and just putting $<(d+\delta)B,(d+\delta)A>$ as the integrand ?